# webpack externals to bundle automatically

Tags: webpack-2

I have this in my webpack.dev.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry : {
        app : './src/app.jsx'
    },
    output : {
        filename : '[name].js',
        path : outputDir
    },
    externals : {
        "react" : "React",
        "react-dom" : "ReactDOM"
    },
```

So externals will not be bundled at each run. How can I instruct webpack to bundle all the external deps of "app.jsx" to a seperate file?  The seperate file should only include these parts of the external libs which are really needed from "app.jsx".